# Book Recommendations for Inorganic Chemistry Mechanisms

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, books

I am looking for a book which has details or basics to **reaction mechanisms** for inorganic chemistry for highschool level(preferably) or maybe undergrad level.

Basically I am looking for a book which can help teach me inorganic chemistry in such a way which decreases the amount of rote learning and memorising , but gives concepts/explanation for things. Like in organic chemistry we have mechanisms , and different things, something like that.

Is there any such book out there ?? Please help !!

I was reading [this link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37303/79319) which has basic resources, but none meet such criteria , please help

Edit: Regarding the question being duplicate: The posts there talk about in general getting started with chemistry. What i am looking for is something more specific which is not covered there in any detail. The book on arrow pushing mostly goes over the reactions of organic chemistry which involve inorganic reagants.

I am looking for something that will teach me inorganic ,not just memorise it.

Eg ,Reasons for the different trends shown by the elements, Reaction Mechanisms , etc ..

PS:For any of my Indian Friends, I am looking for a book helpful for JEE Advanced

Comment: [This](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Arrow+Pushing+in+Inorganic+Chemistry%3A+A+Logical+Approach+to+the+Chemistry+of+the+Main+Group+Elements-p-9781118924532) would surely meet your criteria

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN  Actually it covers a lot of Organic reactions with the inorganic reagants , I want a bit more purely inorganic type.....

For any of my Indian Friends, I am looking for a book helpful for JEE Advanced

Comment: Some very famous reactions are also covered here from the point of view of JEE Advanced and in general,inorganic chemistry in India if you will look carefully. You will find mechanisms(arrow pushing) of the reaction of P4 and NaOH to give PH3,thermal decomposition of NH4NO3 and NH4NO2,and reaction of S2Cl2

Comment: These are the few reactions which I remember from this book... You will just have to look carefully

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN Okay!! , I had Just skimmed through the book ...

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN But I think you would agree , that these are very  scanty

Comment: No in this book,you will find a list of indicators for drawing out inorganic mechanisms yourself,and then a few famous reactions are made by the authors... The idea is to learn the art of drawing inorganic mechanisms,so that you can draw out mechanisms for other reactions you come across in your chemistry course